# Salesforce toolkit for .NET UsernamePasswordAsync hanging

Tags: .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I have this code:

```
public class SalesforceAccess
{
    private static Salesforce.Force.ForceClient _sfclient;
    public static Salesforce.Force.ForceClient SFClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sfclient != null)
                return _sfclient;//-------------------------------------------------------------

            SetSFClient().Wait();
            return _sfclient;
        }
    }

    private static async Task SetSFClient()
    {
        //create auth client to retrieve token
        var auth = new AuthenticationClient();

        //get back URL and token
        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password);
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        var instanceUrl = auth.InstanceUrl;
        var accessToken = auth.AccessToken;
        var apiVersion = auth.ApiVersion;

        _sfclient = new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion);
    }


    public static MyUser GetMyUser(string ID)
    {
        string query = "SELECT  Name, 
                ",City__c " +
                ",State__c " +
                "From SF_Table where " +
                "Name='+ID.ToString()+"'";

        //async call - create task and wait for completion          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        Task<Salesforce.Common.Models.QueryResult<object>> task = SFClient.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);
        task.Wait();
        Salesforce.Common.Models.QueryResult<object> sfData = task.Result;

        <<Parse sfData>>
    }
}
```

If I use SalesforseAccess class from console application it works fine.
However when I use it from the web MVC app on IIS it hangs at the following line:

```
await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password);
```

Does anyone have an idea what may be happening here? Why does it behave differently? And how can this be avoided?

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling `SetSFClient()`? I suspect the deadlock is occurring there. Very generally speaking, you will need to propagate the usage of async/await further up your code. See [Why does this async action hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14526377/54026)

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger (Sorry if you've got more than one notification) I have added a function that uses SF. My biggest confusion is why is it behaves differently. Is it because console app exits after the call and web app is running forever?
Should I dispose AuthenticationClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a deadlock occurring on the UI thread. It is both stuck waiting for the result to come back **AND** waiting for the UI thread to become free so it can return the result on the captured context thread.

This is explained well in [Why does this async action hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14526377/54026).

You will need to follow one of the three suggested solutions:

1. The preferred approach - make your GetMyUser method async. Continue propagating async/await as far back as you need to.
2. Rewrite the Force.com .NET Toolkit so it doesn't use async/await or switch to another library that doesn't use it.
3. Use `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` to override the default behavior of resuming on the captured context.

Comment: _Rewrite the Force.com .NET Toolkit so it doesn't use async/await or switch to another library that doesn't use it_              `auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password).**Wait()**;`   would do exactly that right?

Comment: @shlasasha No, it would still be using async/await. By rewrite I meant pull all the source code down from GitHub and remove any reference to the async/await keywords. I was being facetious. That's not really a practical solution as 1) it would be a lot of work. 2) you would then have to maintain your own library to work with the REST API.

Comment: You are right. But it did resolve my deadlock!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use:

```
Task.Run(() => authenticationClient.UsernamePasswordAsync(consumerKey, consumerSecret, username, password, url)).Wait();
```